# Defining Polymer web components without importing them

Tags: polymer, web-component

Is there a way to define Polymer web components directly in the HTML file  for the page where they're used instead of importing them through link tags?

This seems like it would be faster vs having to request a page and then send requests for the web component html files as well. So far all the guides I've seen only reference importing via `<link rel="import" href="/my_component.html" />`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polymer Bundler to reduce the number of network requests concatenating web components and dependencies in one file. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/bundler).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the other answer, it seems like a better approach to worry more about having a clear structure of your files/elements while you're developing, and to let a build script worry about stuff like that.

But since a bundler would basically do the same thing, define all the elements in a file, it's obviously possible. So only to answer the initial question, you can see a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Saulis/1jLepepq/).

So you just have to use multiple `dom-module` tags like:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
...
</dom-module>
<dom-module id="my-inner-element">
...
</dom-module>
```

And multiple calls to `customElements.define`:

```
customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
customElements.define(MyInnerElement.is, MyInnerElement);
```

But I would most certainly recommend against writing your entire application in a single file.